# How to iterate over top 5 lines from a file with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, files

I can iterate over the lines of a file this way:

```bash
while read l; do echo $l; done < file
```

Is there a way to iterate over only the top 5 lines?

Comment: `head -5 file | while read l; do echo $l; done`

Comment: pipe through `head -5`, but see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373

Comment: And yet another option: `n=5; i=0; while read l; do echo $l; i=$(($i+1)); if [ $i -ge $n ]; then break; fi; done < file`

Comment: @JimL. (though you need `IFS= read -r l` to keep the data intact, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/170373 and even then you may get problems if the file is missing the trailing newline, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478720/what-does-while-read-r-line-n-line-mean)

Comment: @ikkachu Thanks. I was merely reciting the O.P.'s definition of "iterate".

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like:

```
n=5
while IFS= read -ru3 line && (( n-- )); do
  printf 'Got this line: "%s"\n' "$line"
done 3< some-file
```

Though, here, if it's about text processing, best would probably be to use a text processing tool:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/.*/Got this line: "&"/;5q' < some-file
```

Or:

```
awk '{print "Got this line: \""$0"\""}; NR == 5 {exit}' < some-file
```

Or:

```
perl -lne 'print qq(Got this line: "$_"); last if $. == 5' < some-file
```

Related:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)
- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to iterate over the first five lines of a file; here are a few. Note that the last ones are the most efficient and are generally [a better way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/100397) to approach this kind of problem than using a shell script loop.

Brute force:

```
{
    OIFS="$IFS" IFS=
    read -r line && printf "%s\n" "$line"
    read -r line && printf "%s\n" "$line"
    read -r line && printf "%s\n" "$line"
    read -r line && printf "%s\n" "$line"
    read -r line && printf "%s\n" "$line"
    IFS="$OIFS" 
} <file
```

A loop:

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))
do
    IFS= read -r line
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done <file
```

Another loop, suitable for small ranges as the expression is expanded before evaluation into a list of all its values (i.e. `{1..5}` is converted to `1 2 3 4 5` *before* execution):

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    IFS= read -r line
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done <file
```

Considering just the beginning of the file, but beware that any variables set in this loop [will not be accessible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/100397) outside of it

```
head -n5 file |
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    done
```

Not using a loop at all

```
head -n5 file

sed 5q file
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `for i in {1..5}` instead of `for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))`. Just to learn, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: It's another variation. Yours expands as `for i in 1 2 3 4 5` and wouldn't necessarily be scalable to (say) `{1..1000000}`, whereas mine _represents_ `i=1; while (( i <= 5 )) do ... ((i++)); done` and should scale to any range.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity The brace expansion would have to be computed and expanded in full before the loop could start. This becomes an issue if you want to run _many_ iterations (256 MB for a million numbers; the list of numbers must be stored in memory). With an arithmetic `for` loop, you only store the loop variable in memory. Traditional `for` loops (the first kind) _always iterates over a static list stored in memory_. See also [bash counting script, counts fine ascending, doing error by counting descending](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/587729)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution), to redirect from the output of `head -n 5 file` rather than just `file`.  Unlike using a pipe from `head -n 5 file`, with process substitution, the while loop runs in the current shell and is able to set/change variables in that shell and otherwise affect its environment - a child process or subshell, e.g. a pipe, is not able to affect its parent's environment.

For example:

```
while read l; do printf '%s\n' "$l"; done < <(head -n 5 file)
```

I'd include an explanation of why I'm using `printf` instead of `echo` and a warning about not using shell to process text, but [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704544) has already done that.  I recommend that you read the links in that answer.